# Return month end dates less than given date and stop at 12 dates in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

Have a bizarre algorithm where I need to return dates that are month end dates less than or equal to a given month end date.

We're essentially creating a dynamic range of dates that's going to be used in a SQL file. So I want to say, given this date 20200315, return me all month end dates less than that given date but STOP at September of 2019. Also, ignore October 2019.

So given 20200331 you would return...

```
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231
20191130
20190930
```

If I were given 20200731 it would return...

```
20200731
20200630
20200531
20200430
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231
20191130
20190930
```

Now here is one more requirement. It needs to be capped at 12 DATES!! So, If i were given 20201130 it would return...

```
20201130
20201031
20200930
20200831
20200731
20200630
20200531
20200430
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231
```

believe this works

```
for i in {1..11}
do
    thisDate=`date -d "$(date -d ${prevDate} +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +%Y%m%d`
    if ((${thisDate} < 20190930)); then
        break
    elif ((${thisDate} == 20191031)); then
        prevDate=${thisDate}
        (( i += 1 ))
    else
        dateRange="${dateRange}'${thisDate}',"
        prevDate=${thisDate}
        (( i += 1 ))
fi
```

done

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A stack trace alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated the problem with my code. Pretty sure it works. Probably not the most concise and cleanest bit of code....

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Well my question was simply how to do it. Then in the time it took for a response i figured it out on my own :)

Comment: Your code doesn't implement the algorithm. With input of "20201130", it will start by outputing "20201031"; and if the output would contain "20191031" you'll have too few lines

Answer (score 1):

The code provided in the question doesn't appear to take into consideration an input date that is itself an actual EOM (End Of Month).

One idea to address an input date that is an EOM would be to add 1 day to the input date thus pushing us into the 'next' month (at which point the 'previous' month's EOM == our input date); for all other dates the 'previous' month's EOM will be the same (eg, 'previous' EOM will be the same for 20200315 and 20200316 (20200315 + 1 day)).

To find the 'previous' month's EOM we'll take a given month's BOM (Beginning Of Month) and subtract 1 day. [NOTE: BOM can be found by setting a date's 'day' component to '01']

One coding idea:

```
$ cat lasteom

# assumes input is in format: YYYYMMDD
# if no input then default to 'today'

prevdate=${1:-$(date '+%Y%m%d')}

# add one day to push an EOM input date into 'next' month;
# for all dates we then truncate the month to get the BOM (ie, set day component to '01')

workdate=$(date -d "${prevdate} +1 day" +%Y%m01)

i=1

while (( i <= 12 ))
do
        # at this point 'workdate' is YYYYMM01; subtract 1 day to get previous month's EOM

        lasteom=$(date -d "${workdate} -1 day" +%Y%m%d)

        # break if we're working with a EOM < 20190930

        [[ "${lasteom}" < '20190930' ]] && break

        # determine new workdate as BOM (Beginning Of Month) of our new lasteom

        workdate="${lasteom:0:6}"01

        # skip? print? exit loop?

        case ${lasteom} in
                20191031)       continue                       ;;
                20190930)       echo "${lasteom}" ; break      ;;
                *)              echo "${lasteom}" ; (( i++ ))  ;;
        esac
done

$ lasteom 20200315
20200229
20200131
20191231
20191130
20190930                    # skipped 20191030; stop @ 20190930

$ lasteom 20200331
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231
20191130
20190930                    # skipped 20191030; stop @ 20190930

$ lasteom 20200731
20200731
20200630
20200531
20200430
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231
20191130
20190930                    # skipped 20191030; stop @ 20190930

$ lasteom 20201130
20201130
20201031
20200930
20200831
20200731
20200630
20200531
20200430
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231                    # stop @ 12 lines of output

$ lasteom 20200930
20200930
20200831
20200731
20200630
20200531
20200430
20200331
20200229
20200131
20191231
20191130
20190930                    # 12 lines is also 20190930
```

Comment: You should only increment `i` if you print something. Consider `lasteom 20200930 | cat -n`

Comment: ah, yes, 'course; I've updated the answer; better? :-)  thanks!

Comment: I'd be inclined to do `[ $lasteom = 20191031 ] ...` and `[ $lasteom -lt 20190930 ] ...` otherwise output is wrong if date provided is earlier than 20190930 (eg. `lasteom 20190901` should be empty)

Comment: good to hear; and thanks, again, to @jhnc for the fine tuning suggestions